# Sending props back to any screen using back button override

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation, react-props

I have only been working with React-Native recently. For this reason, I would need help with the following problem:

I did override the back button action in the header of a stack navigator, to navigate to any screen. I have to "send back" props to the screen xy. I have tried it on several variants, but unfortunately get error messages (because it does not work as I want) or do not get the expected result. I would be grateful for a solution. Thank you!

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
        title: null,
        headerStyle: {backgroundColor: 'transparent'},
        headerLeft: <HeaderBackButton 
                        onPress={() => {
                          this.props.navigation.state.params.returnData(CurrentServiceProvider,'ServiceProvider')
                          navigation.push('digitalCode'),{ Info1: SomeObject, Info2: SomeObject }
                        }}
                     />

})
```

**Edit:**

Screen B:

```
export class ScreenB extends React.Component {

 static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
    title: null,
    headerStyle: {backgroundColor: 'transparent'},
    headerLeft: <HeaderBackButton onPress={() => {
        navigation.state.params.goBackData({SomeObject, 'ObjectIdentifier'});
        navigation.push('ScreenA')}
       }
    />
 })
}
```

Screen A:

```
export class ScreenA extends React.Component {

 getBackData = (data) => console.log(data)

 ForwardNextScreen(){
   this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenB', {goBackData: this.getBackData});
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for editing! I got an error if I am usin "this.props.navigation.state.params.returnData( .... , ' ' )". Do you know what might be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to send data back to previous screen ,the correct way is to declare callback on navigationParams ([Github issue](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1440))

**ScreenA**

```
getBackData = (data) => console.log(data)

changeScreen = () => this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenB', { goBackData: this.getBackData })
```

**ScreenB**

```
this.props.navigation.state.params.goBackData({ 
//your data json or whatever
})
this.props.navigation.pop()
```

Edit

**Please change your from**

```
headerLeft: <HeaderBackButton onPress={() => {
        navigation.state.params.goBackData({SomeObject, 'ObjectIdentifier'});
        navigation.push('ScreenA')}
       }
    />
```

**to**

```
headerLeft: <HeaderBackButton onPress={() => {
navigation.getParam('goBackData')({SomeObject, 'ObjectIdentifier'});
        navigation.pop();
       }
    />
```

Comment: I got an error using your example: "navigation.state.params.goBackData is not a function".

Comment: did it now, you can find it under "Edit"

Comment: How should I handle passing more than one object?

Comment: goBackData is your own function , you can pass what ever you want , You can pass multiple objects and receive multiple objects